# Is there any way to modify the SourceSheets object in Reports

Tags: smartsheet-api

I have a script which periodically creates a new Smartsheet from a template, then imports data into that newly created sheet. I have a series of reports which looks at all of sheets this script creates so that I can present and graph each sheet as well as summarize elements from them and chart them over time.

I've automated most of the process (in PowerShell), except for modifying the reports to include the newly created sheets. I'm wondering if there is some undocumented way I can edit the SourceSheets array in a Report object. I'd like to add the newly created SheetID via an automation so that I can cut out the last step of importing this data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there is no support in the API to modify reports, not even to copy directly (unless is inside a folder or a workspace and you copy the container), you can only share the report, export and other random things, this is one of the less supported features.